# Nodejs: any library to clean json (say comments) when reading from file?

Tags: json, node.js

I'm reading json files in Node.js using `require("fs")`.

Something like:

```
var readJsonFromFile= function(fileLocation, callback){
      fs.readFile(fileLocation, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
            return callback(err);
          }

          data = JSON.parse(data);
          callback(null,data);
    });
}
```

However, I noticed `JSON.parse`:

- doesn't allow comments `// bla` or `/* blaa */`
- requires keys to be quoted.

Although I realize this is technically correct, I'd like to know if any small library exists which cleans my often annotated json-files to guarentee the above. (And no, it's not completely trivial DIY, think `//` as part of valid values, etc. )

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes!  I use JSON.minify by Kyle Simpson for this very purpose:

https://github.com/getify/JSON.minify

It isn't a full-blown Node module, but it works very well for loading JSON-like config files and such.  Note that you still have to quote your keys, but it does allow for comments.

```
var config = JSON.parse(JSON.minify(fs.readFileSync(configFileName, 'utf8')));
```

Comment: Just to be complete: this only solves the comment-issue. Not the "quote"-issue. The parser actually requires Double-quotes on both the keys and values. Still using it though

Comment: Does this module extend the global JSON object? Seems unneeded for such a trivial thing. I wish it was a *'full blown'* module. Do you not have to `require` it anyway?

Comment: @CoryGross You have to load it somehow.  `require()` is a common way, or I suppose you could just put the file contents in your file but I don't see any downside with loading it by `require()`.  Also, there's no bloat here, you can look at the source code yourself.  https://github.com/getify/JSON.minify/blob/master/minify.json.js If you don't like the method, you could always write one yourself.

Answer (score 2):

[HJSON](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hjson) meets all these requirements.

- It's an NPM package
- It can handle `//` comments
- It can handle `/* */` comments
- It can handle unquoted keys.

[You can try it online](http://hjson.org/try.html).

The sample text:

```
{
  # specify rate in requests/second (because comments are helpful!)
  rate: 1000

  // prefer c-style comments?
  /* feeling old fashioned? */

  # did you notice that rate doesn't need quotes?
  hey: look ma, no quotes for strings either!

  # best of all
  notice: []
  anything: ?

  # yes, commas are optional!
}
```

Comment: HJSON looks great. I wish they had more language implementations and a formal syntax spec like json.org.

Comment: Agreed. The behaviour of edge cases (mostly due to unquoted key values) is subject to change, too.

Answer (score -1):

Just use [JS-YAML](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml) to parse your JSON files. YAML is a superset of JSON and supports the features you want.

You don't need to actually use any YAML-specific stuff in your config file if you don't want to; simply use YAML parser as a JSON parser that fixes 3 annoying problems (comments, quoting and trailing commas).

It even comes with a command-line tool to translate YAML into plain JSON:

```
~> echo "{ foo: 10, bar: [20, 30], }" | js-yaml -j /dev/stdin
{
  "foo": 10,
  "bar": [
    20,
    30
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your example indeed works but when I do it with more complex file `cat config.json|js-yaml -j /dev/stdin` then it outputs pure YAML, not JSON.

Comment: YAML is a superset of JSON, but it's not a superset of the superset of JSON that the OP pasted (including two formats of Javascript comment).

Comment: @SteveBennett True. I was addressing the underlying need (“have comments in my config files”), but if the specific comment syntax is required, YAML won't help.