# Whats the cleanest way to repair this JSON object string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I am doing some site crawling, and right now, I find this string of a JSON object

```
{ "results" : [

    {
        id: 775664,
        status: "In-Stock",
        ffmtCenterId: '10601',
        altText: "In-Stock",
        qty: 6
    }

]}
```

and I wan't to convert that to a object using `JSON.parse()` but this doesn't work because there are syntax errors, like you need quotes around the key values. I tried `eval()` but it didn't work.

Does anyone know whats a good way to fix this string so that I can convert it into an object?

Thanks

Comment: If this is the extent of the problem, then fix it by hand.  If you are talking about your JavaScript code, then you should be complaining to the provider of the web service for returning broken JSON.

Comment: [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784612/nodejs-any-library-to-clean-json-say-comments-when-reading-from-file) discusses an option you can try using Node.

Comment: Fixing it by hand won't work as there is many of these strings to fix, so I need a way to automate it.

Comment: I'm confused - is this what you're getting back? There's nothing syntactically wrong with it. http://jsfiddle.net/vof74kwa/

Comment: isn't that just a javascript object? looks like one, and if you parse such an javascript object instead of Json object them it will work as it is suppose to

Comment: @JonathanLonowski he's displaying the object, not the string. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: @omega: It's really unclear what you're doing here. You say you're crawling the web. What does that mean? Do you have a program that's scraping data from the web and you need to turn that into JavaScript objects? Do you have them stored in a text file? Something else?

Answer (score 2):

how did you try `eval()`?

```
eval("var a = " + incoming_string);
var fixed = JSON.stringify(a);
```

`a` is the object, I don't think you need that `fixed` string.

Of course, eval an unknown string is not safe.

Answer (score 1):

The [hjson](http://hjson.org) project seems to be a possible solution. Thier online converter managed to parse your broken structure into proper JSON though there seem to be some quirks in the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Though I see you've commented that you've already found a fix, here's a double `replace()` that worked on this sample as a multiline string:

```
var a = `{ "results" : [

    {
        id: 775664,
        status: "In-Stock",
        ffmtCenterId: '10601',
        altText: "In-Stock",
        qty: 6
    }

]}`

var b = a.replace(/(\w+)(: )/g, "\"$1\" $2" ).replace(/(:\s+)['](\w+)['](,\n)/g, "$1\"$2\"$3" )

var jo = JSON.parse( b )
```

Without the 2nd `replace()`, I was getting JSON.parse errors in Firebug on the `ffmtCenterId` data.